# How to extract substring from a string up to a certain occurrence of a character

Tags: r

How to extract substring from a string up to a certain occurrence of a character.

For example:

```
string <- 'test_file_csv_name.csv'
```

Up to the second occurrence of _

Expected output:

```
'test_file'
```

Comment: Try `sub("([^_]*_[^_]*)_.*", "\\1", string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub`, we can capture the portion of the file name you want, removing the rest:

```
string <- 'test_file_csv_name.csv'
sub("^([^_]+_[^_]+).*$", "\\1", string)

[1] "test_file"
```

Answer (score 1):

are you asking to keep a certain amout of `_`

you can use

```
sub("((.*?_){1}.*?)_.*","\\1",string)
```

change `{1}` to keep the amount of `_` you'd like

Answer (score 1):

Beside using `sub` (e.g. `sub("([^_]*_[^_]*).*", "\\1", string)`) you can use `substr` using the position found by `gregexpr`:

```
substr(string, 1, gregexpr("_", string)[[1]][2]-1)
#[1] "test_file"
```